# Java | Динамичные объекты

Tags: java, объекты

Приветствую.

**Условие задачи:** Имеется класс **User**, в котором есть переменные: *nickname*, *accessLevel*, *id* и другие.

---

**Задача:** при подключении юзера вытаскивается его уникальный номер в системе и сопоставляется с тем, который отправил пользователь. После чего все данные (nickname, accessLevel и прочие) должны занестись в объект класса User с именем, состоящим из уникального идентификатора (для последующего обращения к этому объекту, а не осуществляя бесконечные запросы к базе данных).

Как это можно реализовать чтобы потом не возникало проблем с вытаскиванием содержимого объекта, изменением содержимого и удалением в случае, если юзер ушёл в оффлайн? Знаю, что массивы для этих целей не очень подходят в виду своей прожорливости.

Comment: что за уникальный идентификатор, это не то что используется в поле id?

Answer (score 0):

> при подключении юзера вытаскивается его уникальный номер в системе и
>   сопоставляется с тем, который отправил пользователь.

Откуда вы знаете номер пользователя, если тот который он отправил не верный? Какой ещё уникальный критерий у вас определяет пользователя?

> После чего все данные (nickname, accessLevel и прочие) должны
>   занестись в объект класса User с именем, состоящим из уникального
>   идентификатора (для последующего обращения к этому объекту, а не
>   осуществляя бесконечные запросы к базе данных).

Вы один раз запрашиваете БД и на основе полученных данных создаете объект User и дальше пользуетесь им.

> Как это можно реализовать чтобы потом не возникало проблем с
>   вытаскиванием содержимого объекта, изменением содержимого и удалением
>   в случае, если юзер ушёл в оффлайн?

Если user вышел, логично удалить его объект, вы не знаете вернется он или нет. Если вернется то авторизуется заново, а вы снова достанете данные из БД.

А лучше приведите куски кода в которых у вас проблема. Объясните, что вы пытаетесь сделать и что у вас получается, в чем отличия.

---

Запрос к БД не такая долгая операция, если у вас не несколько миллионов записей в таблице.

Comment: Да хоть миллиард, если чтение по индексу.